# iOS resize container to fit subviews in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I have a UIView with two subviews A and B inside.

They each have their respective heights. 80 + 20 = 100 total height.

What would be the cleanest way in Swift to hide subview B so only subview A would be shown in the UIView container **but more importantly**  that the UIView container would also automatically adjust its height to match its single child?

Similar to what View.GONE does on Android if container's UIView height is set to wrap_content.

See the pic attached, Thanks!!

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65L9t.png)

Comment: Two approaches that I can think of right now. Programatically change frame of containerView to match height of only subView A. That way subview B will be automatically hidden. Second approach would be using constraints and resetting height constraints constant for ContainerView to be 80 instead of 100. That will automatically hide subview B as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have a height constraint for View B set to 20. If you add this as an IBOutlet to your viewController you can set this constraint constant value to 0 and then call view.updateConstraints()

Answer (score 0):

UIView have a sizeToFit funtion to resize and move the receiver view so it

just encloses its subviews.